# What is meant by control transfer for serial communication in android?

Tags: android, serial-communication

What is meant by control transfer in android and how it works i went through the official documentation of [android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#controlTransfer%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20int%29). I understand little bit but when i Google it for how to use and its parameters i was confused here in parameters we use some 0x21 or 0x80 and other different hexadecimal values what was meant by those values represents and how we can change the values for different communications can any one tell me in detail please.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Control transactions are part of the USB spec, used to send status or commands.  See http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml or any spec on USB.  If you don't know that, you're either operating at the wrong level of abstraction or you need to study USB before returning to your code.